# Do I need ODTforVS2017_122011.exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, oracle12c

I have VS2017 and plan to do some C# development that needs to access Oracle 12c database.

I went in Oracle site and downloaded ODTforVS2017_122011.exe. The installation was successful.

But when I tried to declare my connection type OracleConnection, my project does not know it and I can not reference Oracle.ManagedDataAccess. I had to go to Nuget to install them to satisfy the compiler.

So, my curious question is: is the ODT installation from Oracle site necessary or Nuget installation only would suffice? I just do not want to install to much irrelevant stuff that I would not be able to justify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you need the tools, no. They're Visual Studio features, rather than tools needed at execution time.

From the [download page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/odacmsidownloadvs2017-3806459.html):

> Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio enables Visual Studio data features such as Server Explorer integration, TableAdapter Configuration Wizard and Entity Designer and also includes many useful Oracle specific tools.

So you may find it *useful* to have those tools, but I don't believe they're required on every machine where you want to either develop or deploy your application.

Comment: Ah.. Thank you for clarifying them. The tools are only needed if I want to use EF? Anyhow, it is a relief to know it is not required on the machines to my application is to deployed to.

Comment: @user1205746: I strongly suspect they're not *needed* in any case - they just make life easier if you like doing the design graphically. But I don't have confirmation of any of this - I would test to double check as early as possible.